# How to add # in emph in lstlisting package?

Tags: pdftex, listings

my current lstlisting package format is provided below. I am not sure why but the # is not displayed as blue but rather as golden. I wish to make it displayed as the colour that is specified in emphstyle.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{golden}{rgb}{0.83, 0.53, 0.06}
\definecolor{MyBlue}{rgb}{0.18, 0.3, 0.5}

\lstset{frame=tb,
  language=C++,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  numbers=none,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{golden},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=3,
  emph = {\texttt{\#}, ifndef, define, include, RECEIVER_H, SENDER_H, RECEIVERTHREAD_H, SENDERTHREAD_H, HANDLER_H, SHAPES_H},
  emphstyle = {\color{MyBlue}},
  morekeywords = {},
  escapechar={|}
}


\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
#ifndef SHAPES_H
#define SHAPES_H

#include |\color{dkgreen}<QPoint>|
#include |\color{dkgreen}<QRect>|
#include |\color{dkgreen}<QPainterPath>|
#include |\color{dkgreen}<QList>|
#include |\color{dkgreen}<QPolygon>|
#include |\color{dkgreen}<QtMath>|
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

Comment: As always on this site you are more lilely to get any help if you provide a full but minimal example, not sniplets like this, that others can copy and test as is. In addition it might be an idea to provide an image of what this looks like at your end for easier comparison.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. I've edited my question and hope this explains much better.

Comment: That is still two sniplets, please make this only one single example others need to copy and test _without having to add or modify anything_.

Comment: @daleif The code is now edited to provide the simplest example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `#` character with `literate`. (I didn't get the golden color, just black from your MWE)

[image: a]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{golden}{rgb}{0.83, 0.53, 0.06}
\definecolor{MyBlue}{rgb}{0.18, 0.3, 0.5}

\lstset{frame=tb,
    language=C++,
    aboveskip=3mm,
    belowskip=3mm,
    showstringspaces=false,
    columns=flexible,
    basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
    numbers=none,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
    keywordstyle=\color{golden},
    commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
    stringstyle=\color{dkgreen},
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    tabsize=3,
    emph = {ifndef, define, include, RECEIVER_H, SENDER_H, RECEIVERTHREAD_H, SENDERTHREAD_H, HANDLER_H, SHAPES_H},
    emphstyle = {\color{MyBlue}},
    morekeywords = {},
    literate=*%  added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    {\#}{{\textcolor{MyBlue}{\#}}}{1},
    escapechar={|}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}
        #ifndef SHAPES_H
        #define SHAPES_H        
        #include |\color{dkgreen}<QPoint>|
        #include |\color{dkgreen}<QRect>|
        #include |\color{dkgreen}<QPainterPath>|
        #include |\color{dkgreen}<QList>|
        #include |\color{dkgreen}<QPolygon>|
        #include |\color{dkgreen}<QtMath>|
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```